# Django URLConf include from sub-app not working

Tags: django, url-routing, django-urls, django-apps

I am trying to include a Django sub-app's urls into the main urls.py.

app/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    ...
    include('transfers.urls'), 
)
```

app/transfers/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^transfers/$', 'some.view'),
    ...
)
```

But I get a route not found error. The last element of the route is just the URLconf module from the sub-app. It has not been delisted into the parent URL list.

```
Using the URLconf defined in app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1.
2.
...
30. <module 'transfers.urls' from '/path/to/app/transfers/urls.pyc'>

The current URL, transfers/, didn't match any of these.
```

When I copy the first URL pattern from transfers.urls into the main urls.py, it works. I seems to be including the sub-app urls.py, but I am not sure if in the right way.

How can I get this to work properly?

Comment: i would recommend you read this carefully or you may loose alot of time debugging for just adding an additional $ sign or dash. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
url(r'^transfers/', include('transfers.urls', namespace="transfers")),
```

Then you can use `host:port/transfers/transfers/`.

These two `transfers` are different. The first one is the one in `app/urls.py`, and the second one is the one in `app/transfers/urls.py`.

Comment: Yes that works, although it adds another "transfers/" to the URLs inside transfers.urls.